# How to find out that the Barcode has been scanned?

Tags: java, android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I have this method to generate a Barcode bitmap:

```
public static Bitmap encodeToQrCode(String text, int width, int height) {
    QRCodeWriter writer = new QRCodeWriter();
    BitMatrix matrix = null;
    try {
        matrix = writer.encode(text, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 400, 400);
    } catch (WriterException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height - 1; y++) {
            bmp.setPixel(x, y, matrix.get(x, y) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
    return bmp;
}
```

Is there any way to find out that the Barcode has been scanned? I'm using zxing.

Comment: Either I don't get what you want or I have to ask you: *seriously*? How should this magic happen? Or is it rather that you're trying to implement some scanning feature and want to know when zxing decoded something? In that case: Why do you think the code you use to create a QR code should be relevant to the question? Don't you think the code you use to *scan* the barcode would be relevant in that case?

Comment: why that should be not seriously? i just ask if there is a way or not? if you dont understand what i want i can explain it to you: when the user scan the barcode i shown IN THE APP not in printed form or so, i asked if there is a way to know that the user has scanned the barcode.

Comment: No, your question is: Here, I create a bitmap with a qr code, how do I know whether it was scanned? That's the same as: Here, I took a photo and printed it. How do I know someone looked at it? If you want to know how to scan a barcode/2D code, it is totally irrelevant how you created the code. You need to show us the code you use to scan the code. And you need to ask the right question.

Comment: Yes i understand what do you mean. I never used yxing, i thought maybe zxing has this functionality to find out that the barcode hast been scanned in the APP not in orinted form . The Problem is that the user can use any Barcode Scanner to scan the Barcode, so i dont have the control about the code to scan the barcode

Comment: Aha, so you want to display the barcode and then you want to perfom some action if some other user with a different app scanned the code? That's not possible.

Comment: ah ok thank you, thats the answer i looked for :)

Comment: I'm going to write this as an answer then.

Comment: If the qr stores a url, the server can receive the call and tell you the qr was readed and the url called, but its impossible to tell if the qr was scanned without the server call.

Comment: yes the qr code store a url. but i would like to know it when the code is just beeing scanned but not when the url is opened! like #Torsten said Unfortunately  this is not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you're looking for a way to

1. Create a bitmap that contains a QR code
2. Display that bitmap on your device
3. Detect when a different device that doesn't use your software scans that code

This is not possible. The QR code bitmap is just that: A bitmap your app displays. And a barcode scanner app simply takes a photo of your display and tries to find patterns in that bitmap.